# Failure to execute the creation code dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I enter codes into my website via JavaScript. But I do not know why the codes are not executed after entering this code on my website?

this code: `' $( "#dialog" ).dialog({   backgrouncolor:"red",' ...`

Friends, what should I do to execute the code?

```js
document.querySelector("#scr").innerHTML=
    ' <script>$( "#dialog" ).dialog({   backgrouncolor:"red",'+
   '   height: 298 ,'+
'  width: 454,'+
  'resizable: true,'+
  'draggable: true,'+
   'autoOpen: true,'+
      ' show: {      effect: "fade",      duration: 1000    },'+
       'hide: {      effect: "fade",      duration: 1000    } '+
     '  });'+
 ' $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );  });;</script>'
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="scr"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo, it's not backgrouncolor, it's backgroundcolor.
Second, there is not option in JQuery UI Dialog called backgroundcolor.
To specify a background color for your dialog you can just add a css function after your dialog initialization like this:
`$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ .....}).css("background","red");`